# python: how to split excel files grouped by first column

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a table that needs to be split into multiple files grouped by values in  column 1 - serial.

```
+--------+--------+-------+
| serial |  name  | price |  
+--------+--------+-------+
| 100-a  | rdl    |   123 |  
| 100-b  | gm1    |  -120 |  
| 100-b  | gm1    |   123 |  
| 180r   | xxom   |    12 |  
| 182d   | data11 | 11.50 |  
+--------+--------+-------+
```

the output would be like this:

```
100-a.xls
100-b.xls
180r.xls etc.etc.
```

and opening 100-b.xls cotains this:

```
+--------+------+-------+
| serial | name | price |  
+--------+------+-------+
| 100-b  | gm1  |  -120 |  
| 100-b  | gm1  |   123 |  
+--------+------+-------+
```

I tried using Pandas to define the dataframe by using this code:

```
import pandas as pd
#from itertools import groupby

df = pd.read_excel('myExcelFile.xlsx')
```

I was successful in getting the data frame, but i have no idea what to do next. I tried following this [similar question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35997013/split-xls-file-with-python), but the scenario is a bit different. What is the next approach to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a groupby but a filter.

You need to follow 2 steps :

1. Generate the data that you need in the excel file
2. Save dataframe as excel.

Something like this should do the trick -

```
for x in list(df.serial.unique()) :
    df[df.serial == x].to_excel("{}.xlsx".format(x))
```